# What does this 'that' mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> #### Optional depictive predicatives as adjuncts
>
> Obligatory predicatives are clearly complements, dependent on the occurrence of an appropriate verb.  With optional ones, however, there are grounds for saying that while the resultatives are complements, the depictives are adjuncts. Resultatives are either obligatory (as in the *He talked himself hoarse* construction) or else need to be licensed by the verb.  Optional depictives, however, are less restricted in their occurrence.  One manifestation of this has just been noted: they can occur in transitive clauses with either S or O as predicand.  Another is that they can occur in combination with an obligatory predicative or in the ditransitive construction:
>
> ```
> 29  i) They look even more fantastic naked.
>    ii) They served us our coffee black.
> ```
>
> We will therefore regard such predicatives as adjuncts, **so that the predicative/non-predicative contrast cuts across that between complements and adjuncts**.
>
> Like numerous other kinds of adjunct, predicatives may be integrated into the structure as modifiers, or detached, as supplements:
>
> ```
> 30  i) They left empty-handed.                                 [modifier]
>    ii) Angry at this deception, Kim stormed out of the room.  [supplement]
> ```
>
> (* [This long words](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26780/when-adjectives-become-predicatives-do-they-also-become-adverbs?answertab=active#tab-top) were typed by @snailboat: Only a little of which were originally posted by me, and then he added the long words to clarify my question , thankfully.)

This highlighted part, *so that ~ that between complements and adjuncts*, is very hard to understand. Above all, I can't guess what '*that*' in the words means. Can you explain the meaning of the *that* and the whole meaning?

Comment: You seemed not to have a problem [several weeks ago](http://bestanswer.co/ext/11151437/stackexchange.com/26244117). You can discard the first highlighted "that" if you want to, so obviously it's not important to ask what it "means" - it's just a component of the syntax.

Comment: (As to the rest of it, it's just saying *predicative/non-predicative* and *complement/adjunct* must perforce be treated as orthogonal classifications.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers In fact, the contents were and still are hard to understand, after that question I bought the writhers' other book ‘A Students Introduction to English Grammar’ to know better. Now reading it, I look over the part that I don’t understand. When there are lots of questions in a part, it’s hard to question all of them. And further, even I don’t know what on earth I don’t know, would be a sure fact. I must make some questions, some time, from the same quotation, I think. I hope your good answers will be there too, thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing here. Not having the whole page of it and not having read CGEL, I can only try to understand the sentence as it is. I think what the authors mean is, *"... so that the predicative/non-predicative contrast cuts across that **(contrast)** between complements and adjuncts."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, let's break it down. I think in order to understand the highlighted part, we need to make sure the sense of the preceding clause is clear...

> ***We will therefore*** (because of points made earlier in the text, this is what we'll do)
>    ***regard*** (categorise, treat as)
>    ***such predicatives*** (the ones mentioned earlier)
>    ***as adjuncts*** (those predicatives will be classified as "adjuncts")

As @Dora says, you can then interpret ***so that*** as "thus" or "in consequence" (or "in such a way that"). That's to say *because* we're going to categorise some "predicatives" as "adjuncts", the following statement logically follows...

> *the predicative/non-predicative contrast cuts across that between complements and adjuncts.*

A grammatical contrast/distinction can be made between *predicative* and *non-predicative* clauses. Apparently this distinction is normally thought of as being much the same as the distinction between *complements* (which are "predicates") and *adjuncts* (which are "non-predicative"). I'm not going to try and prove this by analysing the complex argument being made in the preceding text, but clearly this is the implication of the point being made in the highlighted text.

> ***the predicative/non-predicative contrast*** (the first distinction)
>    ***cuts across*** (goes through, disregards, is not related to, is orthogonal to)
>    ***that*** (the other [contrast])
>    ***between complements and adjuncts.*** (just spells out what that other contrast actually *is*)

Since (apparently) *predicates* and *complements* are normally thought of as being the same thing, and *complements* and *adjuncts* are normally thought of as being *different* things, you wouldn't expect that a predicative clause could be classified as an adjunct. But for reasons (apparently) explained in the preceding text, the authors here intend to do treat *predicative/non-predicative* and *complement/adjunct* as two independent distinctions, making it possible for a clause to be both *predicative* ***and*** an *adjunct*.

---

TL;DR: The second highlighted ***that*** stands for *that **contrast*** - being the one between *complements* and *adjuncts* (as opposed to the one between *predicative* and *non-predicative* mentioned earlier in the text).

Comment: Frankly, yours is more complicated for me. Now I get this idea: the authors regard those optional predicatives as adjunct. So that the predicative/non-predicatve (Ahead of the ship, the captain saw an island on which to land  ‘ahead of the ship’ is non-predicative (CGEL,p.604)) contrast is contrary to the contrast between complement and adjunct. Because those predicative and non-predicative adjuncts are both optional, while complement is obligatory and adjunct optional. Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Listenever: I don't know exactly what *predicates, complements* and *adjuncts* are (and I don't really care), so I have no opinion on how those categories apply in your example. All I've done is try to explain what your highlighted phrase means (not very successfully, apparently! :) I'll try another way - essentially, *both **complements** and **adjuncts** can be either **predicative** or **non-predicative***. You're the one reading the book, wherein I assume they define those terms (as they wish to use them, which may not be the same as other writers).

Answer (score 2):

You can replace that "so that" with "thus" or "in consequence."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Tyler: It's not entirely clear exactly what *part* of the highlighted section is causing OP's problem. Given the context, I think we must assumer OP understands that *predicative/non-predicative* and *complement/adjunct* are grammatical categories (and that any given clause can be classed as either *predicative* or *non-predicative*, and either *complement* or *adjunct*). So it's not unreasonable to assume that **so that** is the problematic element for OP.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I remain unconvinced that this isn’t more of a comment than an answer.  It’s less explicative (albeit more accessible) than [your own comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30417/what-does-this-that-mean/30425#comment-56115), for starters.

Comment: @Tyler: I've laboriously deconstructed the entire highlighted text, but I'm not sure I see much point. The preceding paragraph is so dense and full of specialised terminology I'm not even going to attempt to work out exactly what argument it's making. I cannot for the life of me see how anyone who doesn't have exceptionally good command of English would expect to learn anything from such text. People who can easily follow it probably aren't what I would call "learners".